# Updating DataGridView every second

Tags: c#, datagridview

Having some huge lag in my app with the datagridview. I need to update it with status message each second, around 3000 rows are in the datagridview.

The code i currently use to update is:

```
    private void UpdateProxies()
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
                       delegate
                       {
                           this.dgvProxies.DoubleBuffered(true);
                           this.dgvProxies.SuspendLayout();
                           this.dgvProxies.DataSource = null;
                           this.dgvProxies.DataSource = this.Proxies;
                           this.dgvProxies.ResumeLayout();
                           this.dgvProxies.Refresh();
                       }
                       ));
    }
```

I have tried to remove the autoresize properties and enable double buffering.. still *very* laggy

Any ideas how i can speed it up?

Comment: Can you update the objects in the datasource or do you need to destroy and recreate them every time? If you can update them you can use the INotifyPropertyChanged on them and the grid will update the cells it needs to without rebinding to everything. The same with the collection itself, you could use ObservableCollection and the datagrid should handle the changes when needed.

Comment: Try only updating the rows that the user can see.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just impossible to do this way. 3k rows is huge amount of work. I suggest you to try change approach.

- Show only rows that user is viewing currently plus some buffer for scrolling. Make dynamic loading when user is scrolling.
- Make a delta updates. Detect changes in data and add new rows or insert it, or delete or do whatever you need to do accordingly to data changes. Avoid to bind all your data to datagridview.

Comment: How would i implement a solution to show only data that the user is seeing? and then update it when they are scrolling?

Comment: You could bind only part of data. Make a temporary collection. There is OnScroll event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.onscroll.aspx. You could hook up it and make data selection on pair to scroll.